# I am trying to get only the value of a field in firestore using python but it returns a key value pair instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am linking my application with cloude firestore and I am using python for it and I need to retrive the value "Balance" field for checking if it is valid. but when I try to retrieve it I get  outputs like this

```
{ Balance: 80 }
```

But I need only the integer/float value of the balance.
My code is as follows-

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

# Use the application default credentials
cred = credentials.Certificate("/Users/admin/Downloads/serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()
user_id= 'my user id in database'
u = 80
userbal_new= u-10
users_ref = db.collection(u'users').document(user_id)

#update balance
#users_ref.update({u'Balance': userbal_new})

#get balance
get_bal= users_ref.get({u'Balance'})
bal = u'{}'.format(get_bal.to_dict())
print (bal)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're using the `to_dict` function here:

```
bal = u'{}'.format(get_bal.to_dict())
```

This is generating a dictionary, you can call the `bal` dict afterwards like so:

```
bal['Balance']
```

Alternatively, make the call in the format (if it's *always* balance that you want):

```
bal = u'{}'.format(get_bal.to_dict()['Balance'])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the field_paths you want returned in the snapshot with the `db.collection().document().get()` by passing `field_paths={}`

```
get_bal = users_ref.get(field_paths={'Balance'}).to_dict()
```

This will return just the balance in a dictionary:

```
{ Balance: 80 }
```

I find the get() easer to read. So if you only want the int.

```
bal = get_bal.get('Balance')
```

or

```
bal = users_ref.get(field_paths={'Balance'}).to_dict().get('Balance')
```

will return

```
80
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting bal = { 'Balance': 80 }
then for getting the balance use ..
print(bal['Balance'])